# Get wm_windowmoving for a native windows app from C#

Tags: c#, windows-messages

I need to watch an app written in c++ and know when it moves so my c# windows form app can move with it.

I can poll the c++ app's position with a timer but want a better solution.

How can I watch the windows messages for the one app to see if it is moved?

Can it be done?

Or will I need to find a C++ dll to do it or have one written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SetWindowsHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [WH_CBT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) hook which will notify you went the window moves.

See [How to set a Windows hook in Visual C#.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804) or [p/Invoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowsHookEx.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to poll the C++ app from the C# app, it would probably be best to push the data from the C++ app to the C#, that way you get rid of the unnecessary polling (which I am assuming is why you don't want to poll the C++ via C#).

To do this you could use [WM_COPYDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to be able to send the data from the C++ application to the C# application.

Comment: Sorry I should have said I don't have access to the C++ code :(